# To open bootstrap 4 modal by calling method in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am using **[bootstrap 4 modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h)** in my angular app(v6):

**CODE:**

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now i will open the modal by clicking `open` button. This works fine.But instead of opening it manually, On clicking `open` button i need call `method/function` for ex:

```
open() {
     if('Some condition'){
       // Don't open the modal
     } else {
        // Open the modal
     }

   }
```

In the `open()` method if condition fails `modal` should open, else should not.How can i achieve this using only `typescript`

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7tgotw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `@ViewChild` directive  to achieve this.  Just add below code :

```
<!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal"  #content>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      ...... further code
```

in your component.ts file  :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

     @ViewChild('content') content: any;
     public  ngOnInit() {
  }

   public open() {
     if(!true){
       // Dont open the modal
     } else {
        // Open the modal
        this.content.open();
     }

   }
```

Updated stackblitz :  **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckggpk**

Comment: You are not calling method `open` when the button is clicked.

Comment: Please edit in this link: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwkjqz?file=src/app/app.component.html** Here i have added my condition inside the method`open()`.

Comment: In button `open` you are not calling `open() method` like this :  `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="open()">`

Comment: I did. can you refresh the window

Comment: Bootstrap modal uses jquery to toggle modal,make sure it is imported in your app

Comment: Not the issue with jquey, I told that in `html` i,e in  button `open` You are not calling then method `open()`. I want to open the modal by calling the `function/method` not manually.

Comment: you have not added any `click` function to button.

Comment: This is not working

Comment: @GouthamHarshith what version of Angular you're using ?

Comment: @programoholic Angular 8

Answer (score 3):

You can also show do this using *ngIf to modal dialog with some boolean value.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  showModalBox: boolean = false;

     public  ngOnInit() {
  }

   public open() {
     if(0){
       // Dont open the modal
       this.showModalBox = false;
     } else {
        // Open the modal
        this.showModalBox = true;
     }

   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" (click)="open()" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div *ngIf="showModalBox" class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ngwu1

Comment: I am not using any boolean, Just added the string as `true` to check the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Using ng bootstrap you can do . bootstrap modal demo  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2e63j?file=app%2Fmodal-basic.ts

more information refer this https://ng-bootstrap.github.io